# Improper display of certain webpages by PC browser

Tags: browser, webpage

Ever since the last few days. None of my web browsers have been able to display the wikias properly. The same problem also occurs wih MSN and sometimes with ign.com. I am currently on a windows 10 machine and as of current have a 1Mbps connection. So I don't think there is an issue with speed. Next I turn my attention to the web browser and Have used Firefox Chrome and Edge all of which offer the same result That is no improvement. What is it that I can do to help my situation

**Edit 1:** different DNSs don't work. I have tried about 7 of those and nothing seems to be working

**Edit 2:** Yep I am at home and have definitely not messed up with my router settings and am sure the the ISP is not playing tricks on me because the sites seem to load fine when I acessed them from my friends laptop.

A screenshot [gta wikia](https://gta.wikia.com):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try a different DNS server

Comment: See if any error in the console of dev tools. Also is this at home? Seems like certain resources are blocked,  by either yourself, your PC,  firewall,  router,  ISP etc

Comment: Try [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). This solved problems like this for me.